# Как подключить файл из другого сайта?

Tags: php

Здравствуте подскажите как подключить фал с другого сайта тоесть есть 10 сайтов или больше и кним нужно подключать собственую рекламу с магазина с одного какого то центрального сайта чтоб не бегать на все менять рекламу и потом чтоб только на один приходили сообщения ну я думаю способом джет это пробовать и тп, как к всем сайтам подключить фал скажем dat, php

Comment: Можно попробовать в извращённом виде сделать через IFRAME . конечно правильнее будет написать систему к которой будут подключаться остальные через API

Comment: спасибо за ответ, думал я через IFRAME но , а как написать такую систему в какую сторону брать

Comment: Это очень глобальная логика и тут её не описать, попробуйте погуглить и найти бесплатные скрипты (или платные) или же описание что и как делать. google-> free ad dashboard

Comment: А где URL сайта откуда подключаем файл прописывать в функции что выше\ниже

Answer (score 0):

```
$url_ads = 'http://site.com/ads.php';
$ads = file_get_contents($url_ads);
echo $ads;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я и так делал не работает , может в хтачес шо писать

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос так

```
$url3 = $sym_link . 'data/reklama3.dat';

function get_reklama3($url3){
$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $url3);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$data3 = curl_exec($ch3);
$httpcode3 = curl_getinfo($ch3, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch3);
return ($httpcode3>=200 && $httpcode3<300) ? $data3 : false;
}

if ($sym_link_pass == 1)
    {
    $reklama3 = '';

$reklama3 = get_reklama3($url3);
    }
elseif ($sym_link_pass == 2)
    {

    }
```

Comment: типерь возник еще один вопрос файл прочитал целиком таким способом а вот как вывести информацию из переменой через curl